# What is the name of the picture used in Stack Overflow profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar

Is there an official name for the type of image/avatar used as the default profile picture in Stack Overflow?

I have kept mine (check my pic) as an example. Is there a name for this kind of images? I know it is used in other forums and websites but I can't figure out what they are called.

Comment: Check out this question on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated

Comment: To the OP - this was migrated to meta because it relates to the Stack Overflow site itself, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default geometric pattern is called an [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

In the case of Stack Exchange profiles, these are generated for the site by Gravatar.com; it is one of the [4 different automatically generated images](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) they offer.

Fun fact: on April 1st, 2010, **all** avatars on the site were replaced by [Unicorn avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns) generated using similar techniques.

Comment: Funner fact - you can implement the unicorns permanently using Greasemonkey.

Comment: @Compass: funnest fact: several users have permanently switched to the Unicornify image as their profile picture.

Comment: I'll believe it when I see it!

Comment: @Compass: https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers, https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman, https://stackoverflow.com/users/227665/codaddict, etc.

Comment: Still skeptical. Need an unbiased source :P

Comment: @Compass: go post on [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) then. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

They are called Gravatars. It stands for [Globally Recognizable Avatar](https://en.gravatar.com/).

As someone pointed out in the comments, the *type* of image that they are is an Identicon, which is loosely ['a visual representation of a hash value'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

Comment: Actually, they are not Gravatars. They are served *by* Gravatar.com, but they are *called* [Identicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

Comment: Gravatar serves images that aren't just identicons, Stack Overflow allows the use of images that aren't identicons, thus... that's also written in my answer O_o

Comment: Sure, but that's not the name of the *geometric pattern* that is the default image.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the answer on Stack Exchange [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

According to the answer on that page they use a program called Gravatar to create the images.

[Gravatar Implementation](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/)